# Power series and integrals

Tags: integration, power-series

n=0,1,2,3.....~$t→(0 \leq x< \infty)$

$A(x)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}a(n)\times x^{n} $~$A(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}a(t) \times x^{t} dt$

Write the discrete power series formula as the integral form of the continuous function.I can't understand if this is true,are they exactly equivalent.

[image]

The summation just sets the interval of the Riemann sum to 1, while the integral needs to set the interval to infinitesimal.

What am I missing, I'm taking an online course and one of its course notes is about Introduction to Laplace Transforms.

Comment: What do the two $\sim$ symbols you have included mean? They do not correspond to any common use of $\sim$ that I am aware of. What the significance of $t$ in the top line, when the only other use of $t$ is as a dummy variable in the integration (outside of which that $t$ has no definition)? And I suppose the summation should be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair
t is generally defined as time. Sorry, this may just be an intuition. I haven't searched for it, and if I keep exploring, this may be hard for me. I'm just starting to learn about Laplace transforms and just know it's Definition, I don't know where it came from.

Comment: I did not ask for the meaning of $t$. I asked what was the significance of its use in the top line when it is only a dummy variable in the rest. And I asked what $\sim$ means in your two uses of it. YOU wrote those symbols down. If you wrote them down without even knowing what they mean, you are just speaking in gibberish. If you are just copying from some other source, you need to look up what they mean in that source.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair  Course address:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ2qulI6GEk&list=PLEC88901EBADDD980&index=19,If written as Riemann sum, it seems to be the sum of continuous functions. But the extra "dt" is incomprehensible, and I don't need "dt" at all.

Comment: I do not have the 47 minutes to waste waiting for the particular part of the lecture to come up. Can you give me a timestamp?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair 3:08

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Thanks!this may be an intuition, or it may be wrong. The professor just wants the students to imagine. If the topic is wrong. There is no need to discuss it. You are right.If I really want to know, I think I need to read some books. I just want to know a simple reason.

Comment: He is not claiming that these two expressions are the same thing. He is generalizing from expressions of the *form* $A(x) = \sum_n a_n x^t$ to expressions of the *form* $A(x) = \int a(t)x^t\,dt$. The $A(x)$ in these expressions need not be the same. The $a_n$ or $a(n)$ are most definitely not the same. He is just building an analogy of expressing a function $A(x)$ as a power series, to expressing it by means of an integration instead. You can find such integral expressions for many functions that do not have power series. The "$dt$" is part of integration. You cannot drop it.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair This seems to be just an analogy, and it doesn't matter. If the discrete sum can get a function, it can be expanded with Taylor's formula to get the original expression.Its analogy is the inverse Laplace transform.